# How to get a running value per subgroup?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
testdata

col1
1
2
3
1
1
2
3
...
```

how to arrive at a query that give also the the running number / unique id per subgroup ?

```
col1 | sub_id
1      1
2      1
3      1
1      2
1      3
2      2
3      2
...    ...
```

Comment: In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Hence, "running number" has no meaning without such a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select col1,
       (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.id <= t.id) as sub_id
from table t;
```

You can also do this with variables:

```
  select t.*,
         (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                    if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as sub_id
  from table t cross join
       (select @rn := 0, @id := -1) vars
  order by col1, id;
```